# Separating view_config routing and rendering in Pyramid

Tags: python, render, pyramid

I am attempting to implement a pattern where I use an intermediate function to determine which function to call and have the final function do the rendering, but the flow does not end up rendering. What am I missing? Is there a way to tweak this to make it work?

Here's what I'm attempting.

```
@view_config(route='fork_route')
def fork(self):
    x = True
    if x:
        self.my_func1
    else:
        self.my_func2
    #I expected it to render before this point
    return dict({'msg':'failed'})

@view_config(renderer="templates/derived/template1")
def my_func1:
    return dict({'msg':'msg1'})

@view_config(renderer="templates/derived/template2")
def my_func2:
    return dict({'msg':'msg2'})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid's renderers are pretty simple, and in the end it's "just python". Meaning you're calling functions from functions, nothing special.

The way Pyramid's automated rendering works is:

1. Request comes in, gets dispatched to a view.
2. If *that specific view* view does NOT return a Response object, then Pyramid attempts to pass the value you returned from the view into the attached renderer.

The `view_config` is only relevant to the current request's view. The other functions you are calling are simply functions in Python.

If you still want to delegate the work to another view then there are several options, but the one we tell people is that you will need to explicitly call `pyramid.renderers.render` within the sub-view or `render_to_response`. Of course if you only call `render` then you must turn that html body into a full `Response` object.

```
def fork(request):
    return myfunc1(request)

def myfunc1(request):
    return render_to_response('templates/derived/template2', {'msg': 'msg1'}, request)
```

Notice how `myfunc1` returns a `Response` object so `fork` (the view that is active for this request) can just return it.

Otherwise you need to turn the result into a response:

```
def fork(request):
    resp = request.response
    resp.body = myfunc1(request)
    return resp

def myfunc1(request):
    return render('templates/derived/template2', {'msg': 'msg1'}, request)
```

There are obviously benefits and caveats to each approach.

Comment: I wasn't return a full response object in my functions. I've seen all of the rendering methods in the docs but am still learning which one matches each situation. Thanks!